# MySQL: How to update auto-increment for all existing entries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I have an existing table that uses an auto-incremented `id` as its primary key.

There are entries in the table with the id starting at 1:

```
id    field1
==    ======
1     foo1
2     foo2
3     foo3
```

Is there a way to update the `id` for *all existing entries* so the auto_increment starts at another number?:

```
id    field1
====    ======
1000     foo1
1001     foo2
1002     foo3
```

(The order does not necessarily have to be kept if that is not possible)

Comment: There's just no sensible reason for wanting to do this. None.

Comment: The id serves a business purpose. The range of the id changed due to business requirements.

Comment: It shouldn't. That's my point. The value of the id should have significance only to the internal workings of the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `update` to change the values and `alter table` to update the auto increment to a new value:

```
alter table t set auto_increment = 1003;  -- the next value

update t
    set id = id + 999;
```

Comment: Just a reminder is that you cannot update the table's current `auto_increment` to any value below the last used in the table.

Comment: ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = '1003';

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server it is work, MySql I'm not sure

```
DECLARE @NewRowId int = 998;

DBCC CHECKIDENT('MyTableName', RESEED, @NewRowId)
```